# Get Expression Tree for LINQ IQueryable

Tags: linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core, expression, iqueryable

I'm trying to implement my own Remote LINQ execution for EF Core. So, as usual the problem is connected with serialization.
Let's imagine that I have an `IQueryable<T>` object and its `Expression`, something like this:

```
var sameTestData = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
var queryableExpresssion = myTestDbContext.Users.Include(e => e.SameTable1)
                                                .Include(f => f.SameTable2)
                                                .Where(s => sameTestData.Contains(s.Id))
                                                .Select(t => t.FullName)
                                                .Expression;
```

So, I have 2 questions:

1) The main problem is an `MethodCallExpression` identification problem: how to check whole tree and divide `Expression` derived types into 2 collections - with `LambdaExpression` type an other types.

2) Are there any libraries which perform Expression Tree parsing?

Thank you.

Comment: I think you are looking at creating an `ExpressionVisitor`. You may also want to consider the blog series [Building an IQueryable Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/mattwar/linq-building-an-iqueryable-provider-series) and the [IQToolkit](https://github.com/mattwar/iqtoolkit) that is built in the series.

Comment: @NetMage Thank you, I'll check your resourses! I think I shold realize my own ExpressionVisitor, yes, but I thought that there are some already realized ExpressionVisitors. Ehhh... Need to spend more time for my serializer.((((